# Pipeline in Windows batch backquote

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I would like to see how I can use, or escape pipeline in a back quote in windows batch just like in Unix shells. Suppose I have this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %i IN (`date /t`) DO @set TODAY=%i
echo %TODAY%
```

This will give me the date in TODAY variable. But I want to have this 1 or more pipeline working:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %i IN (`date /t | cut -c 1-3`) DO @set TODAY=%i
```

cmd.exe complains err like this I think I need an escape mechanism?

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

So, is this doable? How? Please note that I have full gnu coreutils and most goodies in PATH so I can use cut just as example.

Comment: I guess I'm gonna be shocked if FOR really can do pipelines. In a *nix shell, these things are modular building blocks, but in cmd.exe, everything is just one more wart piled on. Does a backtick work *anywhere* else in cmd.exe?

Comment: This is just an escape issue. I don't know if backtick work out of FOR. In cmd.exe may things work only in FOR :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The escape character is `^`.

Here is the command, with `set` replaced by `echo` at the end to make it SO friendly.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %i IN (`date /t ^| cut -c 1-3`) DO @echo TODAY=%i
TODAY=18/
```

(YMMV, I have a French locale for date)

```
date /t
18/02/2013
```

Comment: Wow! I'm writing this one down.